# How to get rid of message “Leave site? Changes that you made may not be saved”?

Tags: bootstrap-theme

I have a site which are using 2 themes : adminimal and a custom made. 
When submitting a form in adminimal no message appears. In the custom theme based on bootstrap it does. The message is:

“Leave site? Changes that you made may not be saved”

We would like to get rid of it.

It is a thing in Javascript/jquiry.  So when I scan alle code in the custom theme no string is found on this error.. ?!?

It there an option within drupal to disable this check? Within the bootstrap options on 
/admin/appearance/settings/default
there are a lot but I do not understand what option I can/should be use.

Comment: Well it is not that easy to guess what the problem might be. Try to look in your error log to see if anything is there.

Comment: Isn't this a browser thing? We need to know the steps to reproduce your issue. Screenshots would be pretty helpful as well. Otherwise it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Try to take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425682/disable-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-pop-up-window